# What's the expression of "necessarily satisfied" in mathematics?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I want to say:

> Consider a>b, if b>c, then a>c is necessarily satisfied.

Will it be better by using "must"

> Consider a>b, if b>c, then a>c must be satisfied.

or with nothing

> Consider a>b, if b>c, then a>c  is satisfied.

Thank you very much!

More clearly, I want to use "satisfied" because a>c is a constraint where "a" is a variable while "b" and "c" are constants. I want to express that since "a>b", if  "b>c", then constraint "a>c" should not be considered. So how should I express this? Thnaks for your suggestion.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you want a phrase such as "is ... satisfied" or "must be satisfied" at all. Your proof would read more smoothly like this:

Suppose a>b. If b>c, then a>c.

Or, if you want to use "must":

Suppose a>b. If b>c, then a must be greater than c.

Comment: @Rosie F        Sorry for the confusion. I want to use "satisfied" because a>c is a constraint where "a" is a variable while "b" and "c" are constants. I want to express that since "a>b", if  "b>c", then constraint "a>c" should not be considered. So how should I express this? Thnaks for your suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by "consider a>b"? That's the really confusing part of your sentences.  Do you mean "assume a>b"? In math papers "consider" means something like "think about" or "let's look at".

Comment: @Peter Shor     a>b is a conclusion which has been proved. So is there any verb more appropriate?

Comment: I don't think *consider* works. You don't need a single-word verb there, and I can't think of any that are better. You could use *Since we know a>b* or *Having established a>b*, or *The constraint a>b is satisfied, so if ...*, or something like that.

Comment: @Peter Shor    Thanks for your suggestion, that helps me a lot! However, I have another problem. Which verb would you like to use for "condition", "condition xxx holds" or "condition xxx is satisfied" or others? Thank you very much!

Comment: In this case, I'd use *a>c will also be satisfied* or *a>c will also hold*, but I think all your suggestions work.

Comment: The usual way of saying this utilises a 'specifying definition' of _implies [that]_ meaning _demands [that]_.  a > b and b > c implies a > c There is even a special symbol for this sense of 'implies', ⇒ Thus we write ............ a > b and b > c ⇒ a > c

Comment: You could also say that, if a>b and b>c then _it follows_ that a>c and, therefore, if a>=b then we do not need to test for a>c. If a is an unconstrained variable, however, it could take a value such that b>a and a>c or a<=c so it would need to be tested under those conditions.

Comment: Consider a > b; if b > c [is also true], then a > c is necessarily satisfied. <<=>> Consider two numbers a and b where a is greater than b. If a third number c, less than b, is also considered, then the statement/assertion/claim that a is greater than c must be true. //or// Consider two numbers a and b where a is greater than b. If a third number c, less than b, is also considered, then the statement "a is greater than c" is certainly true.

Comment: In a context of this kind, one has to be careful to avoid any ambiguity about what precisely is qualified by *necessarily*. If a>b and b>c are not themselves necessary, then the a>c is not **itself** necessary either; although it is necessarily implied by a>b and b>c.

Comment: If a > b and b > c then a > c.

Answer (score 1):

In a formal system of reasoning, such as mathematics, a statement is *necessarily true* if it is true for all the values that can be assigned to its variables. Generally speaking, this means that the truth of the statement can be determined by symbolic manipulation as opposed to the assigning values and testing the results.

A symbolic constant in such an expression may be thought of as a variable that we hold at a constant value while we allow other variables to change. In mathematics, for example, this simplifies certain operations, such as the differentiation of algebraic functions, but that’s not the key point here.

The expression, “Consider a>b, if b>c, then a>c is necessarily satisfied.” is simple, logical and correct. From it, the reader can infer that it is only necessary to compare *a* against the larger of the two constants *b* and *c*.

The expression is given in isolation, so we don’t know the form of the argument that follows. However, *consider* is typically used in this context to establish a point in the reader’s mind, so that it can be referred to further along.

Most of the suggestions advanced by the commenters are technically correct, but are needlessly heavy and burdensome to the text.

Style, of course, is a matter of opinion, and *de gustibus non est disputandum*, but in my opinion the original was fine.

The ever-useful Wikipedia has quite a lot to say about logic: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic

Answer (score 0):

The use of *satisfied* in this context is confusing.

The entire sequence being referenced is called a *proof*. The final statement in a proof is called a [*theorem*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/theorem):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> 1 : a formula, proposition, or statement in mathematics or logic deduced or to be deduced from other formulas or propositions

From [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_proof) (additional emphasis mine):

> In logic and mathematics, a **formal proof** or **derivation** is a finite sequence of sentences (called well-formed formulas in the case of a formal language), each of which is an axiom, an assumption, or follows from the preceding sentences in the sequence by a rule of inference. It differs from a natural language argument in that it is rigorous, unambiguous and mechanically checkable …
>
> The **theorem** is a syntactic consequence of all the well-formed formulas preceding it in the proof.

If anything is being *satisfied* in the proof, it's the set of axioms that *precedes* the theorem.

---

However, you can say that the theorem is a *necessary* [***conclusion***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conclusion) or a *necessary* [***consequence***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consequence) (of the set of axioms):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **conclusion**
> **1 a** : a reasoned judgment : INFERENCE
>        // The obvious *conclusion* is that she was negligent.
> **1 b** : the necessary consequence of two or more propositions taken as premises
> *especially* : the inferred proposition of a syllogism
>
> **consequence**
> **1** : a conclusion derived through logic : INFERENCE
>     //… we can deduce … many *consequences* each of which can be tested by experiment.
> — James Bryant Conant

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to use "satisfied" because a>c is a constraint where "a" is a variable while "b" and "c" are constants. I want to express that since "a>b", if  "b>c", then constraint "a>c" should not be considered. So how should I express this? Thnaks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Jason: in optimization, constraints "are satisfied" or "hold". I agree you shouldn't use "satisfied" in other areas of mathematics.

Comment: @WangYanping I don't follow. Are you saying that `a>c` is not the theorem of the proof? (Axiom 1) `a>b`; (Axiom 2) `b>c`; (Theorem): `a>c`. That's a classic logical proof. And `a>c` ***should*** be considered, because it's true; in fact it's *necessary*. If it weren't true, then one of the previous axioms would be false.

Comment: @JasonBassford, the OP has never said that a>b and b>c are **axioms**; for all we know, they could be the results of some measurements. This, of course, does not affect the step from a>b and b>c, to a>c, which would still be a matter of deductive logic.